# How do I set the node title as breadcrumb?

Tags: 7, breadcrumbs

How can I set the breadcrumbs for a node? I have a node which is in the menu and also the head menu with the id 2 which contains the imprint.

If I open my page `http://my.page.tld/imprint` (I'm using the SEO stuff) I can see my text with the correct title but with no useful breadcrumbs. It's *Home* instead of *Home » Imprint*.

How can I fix that?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can use [Menu Breadcrumb](http://drupal.org/project/menu_breadcrumb). It allows you to Append the page title to the breadcrumb (either as a clickable url or not) . Or you can edit your theme's page.tpl.php - simply add $title after the $breadcrumb variable.

There are also a ton of other breadcrumb modules if you want to get fancy:

1. [Crumbs](http://drupal.org/project/crumbs)
2. [Custom Breadcrumbs](http://drupal.org/project/custom_breadcrumbs)
3. [Hansel](http://drupal.org/project/hansel)

See an older [comparison chart](http://drupal.org/node/533448).

Comment: I tried already `Custom Breadcrumbs` without success. `Menu Breadcrumb` does its job for the imprint. But not for a taxonomy entry in the menu. I'm keep looking how to fix that.

Comment: `Custom Breadcrumbs` is genius. Use `[node:title]` as title and `[node:url:relative]` as your path.

Answer (score 4):

A simple custom solution would be to add a function like this in your theme's `template.php` file:

```
function MYTHEME_preprocess_node(&$variables) {
  //Retrieve current breadcrumb
  $breadcrumbs = drupal_get_breadcrumb();
  //Add the title without link
  $breadcrumbs[] = $variables['node']->title;
  //OR add the title with a link
  $breadcrumbs[] = l($variables['node']->title, 'node/'.$variables['node']->nid);

  //Set the new breadcrumb
  drupal_set_breadcrumb($breadcrumbs);
}
```

Comment: Code solutions are great too. But the module seems to be easier in this case.

Comment: Of course, it was to give you a very small alternative as a site can be rapidly overloaded with modules ;)

Comment: I used your solution for a second problem. I could add so the breadcrumps for the taxonomies.

Answer (score 3):

Breadcrumbs do not include the name of the current page.  The thought behind this is that  you are on the page and do not need a link to get there.  Breadcrumbs are a link menu that is always one step back, so you can back up quickly.

Comment: Thank you I see now the reason. I think that Google analyses the breadcrumps so it would make sense for the imprint in my opinion. How can I achive that?

Answer (score 0):

Put this code in template.php (and change MYTHEME to your theme name)

```
function MYTHEME_breadcrumb($variables) {
  $variables['breadcrumb'][] = drupal_get_title();
  return theme_breadcrumb($variables);
}
```